# Как в visual studio называется этот компонент?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как в visual studio называется этот компонент?

[image]

Comment: Это `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 3):

Это ComboBox. [Visual Studio C#: обзор ComboBox](http://microsin.net/programming/pc/c-sharp-combobox.html)

Answer (score 0):

Используй класс `dropDownList` для работы с ним [ссылка на документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Если ссылка на msdn, то она должна туда и вести, а не через какие-то дебри всяких врепперов.

Comment: @VladD, я не в курсе, что это за штука.

Comment: Ярослав, поскольку ссылку отредактировали, я восстановил ваш ответ и снял пометки "спам". В текущем виде ответ всё-таки имеет ценность. Но пожалуйста, больше никогда не используйте рекламные и прочие подозрительные непрямые ссылки на этом сайте. Они неизменно будут отмечаться как спам.

Comment: это странно, так как я ссылку копировал с адресной строки, после перехода с гугла